# How to generate a JSON file at build time of a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

Since React Native does not support optional require/import statements, I need to generate a JSON file at build time if the file doesn't exist. I only need to create this file for a React Native Android app. How can this be done?

Comment: You can use packages react-native-filesystem or react-native-fs
Why you need only at bulid time

Comment: Because of the inability to require/import files that might not exist. I hadn't considered reading the file from the filesystem. I wonder how you would do that for files that exist in your app bundle.

Comment: If we do not catch the error and create a new one